# How do I load an mp4 video with multiple audio tracks into blender?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I've recently started using OBS multiplatform to record game play. I currently have it set to record sounds on 2 different tracks. The first for system sounds (like gamesound, mumble, etc.) and the second to record the mic.

I am able to switch between tracks when I play the unedited video using VLC, but when I load the mp4 into blender, I only get track 1.

Did I do something wrong, or does blender vse not support multiple tracks?

Blender after loading mp4:
[image]
VLC video information:
[image]

**UPDATE**

For now, it seems like the solution will be to use an external tool to get the second audio track and import it into blender afterwards.
A [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T46449) has been logged with the Blender bug reporting tool.

**UPDATE 2**

The bug report has been closed/archived with the gist being "not a bug". It has been added to the [TODO list](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Source/Development/Todo/Editors#Video_Sequencer).
If you are looking to have support for multiple audio tracks, I would suggest looking at other video editing software until Blender adds support for this feature.

Comment: You may have to import it sperately

Comment: And maybe you could also file a bug report/feature request, because it could be useful, and not too difficult for devs to implement (it's just typically unusual).

Comment: Rather than updating your question with your answer you should [answer your own question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import video for editing with multiple audio strips](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57822/import-video-for-editing-with-multiple-audio-strips)

Comment: Nearly 5 years later, looks like Blender still doesn't support this.  Something as basic as Audacity has no problem with this.  I think this is a huge feature oversight!

Answer (score 5):

**Blender does not currently support the importing of multiple audio tracks that are encoded into video containers. It will typically import the first track, though I'm not certain.** I recommend that you use a program like Davinci Resolve which is free to use and is much better suited for video editing and has a faster viewport for video editing. I was once in a similar situation like you with multiple tracks of audio when using OBS.