# Import video for editing with multiple audio strips

Tags: video-sequence-editor, edit-mode, audio

I'm recording with OBS.
In OBS, I have two options for audio recording, Desktop Audio and Mic Audio.
Each of these are mixed together and saved in the same MP4 with the video which is recorded.

When I open the .mp4 in Blender, both the Desktop and Mic audio have are in the same audio strip.

How do I separate audio sources and import them for individual editing?

I'd like to have game audio, microphone audio, desktop audio (game?), and other programs (Discord, in my case) all as separate audio strips when I pull it into Blender.

Any ideas as to how I can accomplish this?

EDIT: I should add that I've tried sending video to OBS via Dxtory. I've also tried simply recording with Dxtory only, but I do not seem to be able to record separate audio clips for use in Blender.

Comment: While you may be editing in Blender, this isn't something that can be solved with Blender.  I do not know what OS you are running, but if you have Quicktime (comes with Mac OS X/macOS), then you can have it select the different "microphones" to record with, one for each.  You could then clap or something and drag your audio tracks around to match it up in Blender.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been [asked before](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39817/2843) and there has been a [Bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T46449) which has been closed again, but it's been added to the [ToDo list](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Source/Development/Todo/Editors#Video_Sequencer).

So for now I'd suggest you'd use another tool* to extract your multiple tracks into individual files and import them all manually into the VSE.

* like Audacity with the ffmpeg plugin or VLC via its file saving mode, but that's offtopic here...

Comment: So I don't know what bug people are facing, but with some more researching, I've found that one can right-click the .avi which is saved from DXTory and click Extract Audio Files. My problem seems to be different from what other people are getting.

Comment: You mean in Windows Explorer? Then you have some specific software installed that adds this feature in the context menu of your video files. But that isn't default in Windows. You should be able to switch between your audio tracks in VLC. But Blender isn't capable of importing multiple audio tracks for one video file as for now.