# Video editing multichannel audio

Tags: audio

Is there a way to render a video with multiple audio tracks? I've found these two subjects related to the import of files with several audio channels:

[How do I load an mp4 video with multiple audio tracks into blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39817/how-do-i-load-an-mp4-video-with-multiple-audio-tracks-into-blender)

[Import video for editing with multiple audio strips](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57822/import-video-for-editing-with-multiple-audio-strips)

but nothing related to the export.
Many thanks,